# Adding auto increment column other than primary key

Tags: mysql, sql, primary-key

I have table in which has key is primary key. I want to add `seqNo` key which should be auto incremented but it does not allow to make it as auto increment.

Because there is already one primary key,

Is it possible to make seqNo auto increment? currently `seqNo` is not present. I want to add it

Comment: It should be possible, I'd have thought. In most database systems, auto-increment/identity/sequence numbers, and primary keys are completely orthogonal concepts.

Comment: You cannot do this. And besides, why would you want to?

Comment: @Strawberry: to keep the record that how many to total record I have and which record on whoch numner

Comment: Autoincrement wouldn't do that. Despite its name, that's not what it's for. This is an issue of data display, not data storage and retrieval. DO NOT STORE THIS SEQUENCE ID

Answer (score 1):

You can't have two identity columns in a SQL table but you can still create sequences.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878091.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You have the following options.

1. Make a trigger that increments your column value on every insert statement
2. Use a sequence, but once a sequence value is generated it will never be generated again (meaning, you would get a gap in your values if your insert fails for some reason)

Answer (score 1):

```
 DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test;
 
 CREATE TABLE test 
 ( testID int(11) NOT NULL
 , string varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL
 , testInc int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
 , PRIMARY KEY (testID)
 , KEY testInc (testInc)
 );
 
 INSERT INTO test
 (testID
 , string
 ) values 
 (1
 ,'Hello'
  );
 
 INSERT INTO test (testid,string) SELECT x.testid + y.max_test,string FROM test x JOIN (SELECT MAX(testid) max_test FROM test)y;
 INSERT INTO test (testid,string) SELECT x.testid + y.max_test,string FROM test x JOIN (SELECT MAX(testid) max_test FROM test)y;
 INSERT INTO test (testid,string) SELECT x.testid + y.max_test,string FROM test x JOIN (SELECT MAX(testid) max_test FROM test)y;
 Query OK, 4 rows affected (0.03 sec)
```

```
 SELECT * FROM test;
 +--------+--------+---------+
 | testID | string | testInc |
 +--------+--------+---------+
 |      1 | Hello  |       1 |
 |      2 | Hello  |       2 |
 |      3 | Hello  |       3 |
 |      4 | Hello  |       4 |
 |      5 | Hello  |       6 |
 |      6 | Hello  |       7 |
 |      7 | Hello  |       8 |
 |      8 | Hello  |       9 |
 +--------+--------+---------+
```

[fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d29a5b/1)

The number of rows (8) and the value of testinc (9) are different. This is not what the asker wants. The MAX() trick I've used for generating the PK is also no good, because it's subject to runtime errors.

Storing a sequential id is pointless.

Comment: thanks, but while using phpmyadmin, I added new column seq_no. Set it as index and auto increment. which gives error: multiple primary key define. I have to update exisiting table here to add auto increment column

Comment: `alter table frrole_combined add seq_no varchar(64) not null; ` what's wrong with this?

Comment: @Programming_crazy You're really not going to listen to me, are you?

Answer (score 0):

auto_increment and primary key are separate concepts.  It's the RDBMS that forces the issue.

Having a primary key that is separate from an auto_incremented column is possible.  For instance, the primary key may consist of multiple fields in a table.  Auto_increment makes no sense in that case.  These id fields are not real primary keys; they are psuedo-keys, meant to uniquely number rows in a table for DML purposes.  The primary key refers to what makes the data in the table unique for table normalization.

The restrictions in MySQL about allowing only a single column to have auto_increment and forcing it to be a key is an expedient that is wrong.

One way to do this is in MySQL is to create a table with a primary key other than id, then alter the table to add a unique key constraint:

```
CREATE TABLE protocol (id int not null, name varchar(30) not null primary key);
ALTER TABLE protocol ADD CONSTRAINT constraint_name UNIQUE(id);
ALTER TABLE protocol modify id int not null auto_increment;
```

This will give you an auto_increment id and a primary key assigned to a different column. And it will work with

```
insert into protocol(id, name) values(0,'me');
insert into protocol(id, name) values(0,'you');
insert into protocol(id, name) values(0,'them');
```

Comment: Please avoid meta & social commentary in posts. Read about inline & block formats for code & quotes in the edit help. [Help] [meta] [meta.se]